# How to show different price of every item in its configure item in magento?

Tags: php, magento, product

I have products with 2 flavors and 3 sizes. 
Example: Chips

```
╔════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Price  ║                Product                 ║
╠════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ $140   ║ Chips Original Pack (100 1oz Bags)     ║
║ $145   ║ chips Spicy Pack (100 1oz Bags)        ║
║ $140   ║ Chips Black Pepper Pack (100 1oz bags) ║
║ $59.99 ║ Chips Original Pack(12 3oz Bags)       ║
║ $69.99 ║ Chips Spicy Pack (12 3oz Bags)         ║
║ $69.99 ║ Chips Black Pepper Pack (12 3oz Bags)  ║
║ $76.48 ║ Chips Original Pack (8 8oz Bags)       ║
║ $99.98 ║ Chips Spicy Pack (8 8oz Bags)          ║
║ $76.48 ║ Chips Black Pepper Pack  (8 8oz Bags)  ║
║ $59.99 ║ Chips Pack                             ║
╚════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I have simply created the example above and configure the flavor and size of the items with a drop-down menu. I have used super-attribute for added values. The product page correctly shows the final price when flavor and size are chosen. But if **Spicy Pack (100 1oz Bags)** is selected, it shows a wrong price:

> $140 instead of $145.

I have checked and noticed the same size has two different values i.e. $140 and $145 for (100 1oz bags). Please suggest how to show correct price on product page?

supper attribute for flavor and size

```
Attribute Name:     Use default (Size)

Option: 1oz 100 Bags Price:   80.01

Option: 3oz 12 Bags Price:   10

Option: 8oz 8 Bags Price:   16.49

Attribute Name:     Use default (Flavor)

Option: Original Price:   

Option: Spicy Price:   

Option: Black Pepper Price:
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes then show us.

Comment: http://store.bariatricpal.com/healthy-snacks/hjc-turkey-jerky.html